# Custom Drop Down List Styling (CSS/JS with ASP.NET C# Connection)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

Currently I am using an ASP.net DropdownList as such:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CourseSelectionDropdown" DataTextField="DropdownDisplay" DataValueField="CourseId"
            runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CourseSelectionDropdown_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="True">
```

It looks rather ugly and I'd like to use something like below, which I will customise futher (remove the images, and make each list item double line - quite like the facebook dropdown).

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index2.html#

I'm new to ASP.net, and would like some pointers on how to link up the HTML/JS list items with a method in the C# code.

I have searched for two hours on the internet without any sort of concrete or easy to read solution.

Comment: Assign some class to your `DropDownList` like that `CssClass="myDDL"` and style it using @Diodeus example link by calling `var select = $('select.myDDL');`

Answer (score 0):

Typically you just use a jQuery-based plug-in that will convert your SELECT to more complex, styled HTML.

See: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/